# Can a company handle 70% of all bitcoin trading?

Tags: network

In [this paper about Mt. Gox](https://blogs.wsj.com/briefly/2014/02/25/5-things-about-mt-goxs-crisis/), it is said that:

> By 2013, it was handling 70% of all bitcoin trading.

Doesn't it contradict the 51% rule, saying that if a single agent controls 51% of the bitcoin market, it will collapse?

Comment: This is mixing two different things. 70% of trade is different than 51% of mining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@MaxSan is correct. Mt. Gox was only an exchange where people would buy and sell bitcoin. The 51% rule applies to a single entity (miner/pool) have 51% of the hashing power of the entire bitcoin mining network.